# What type of exterior siding tiles are these?

Tags: tile, exterior

I'm trying to identify these tiles around our windows as a few on the far side are missing/broken and need replacing.

[image]

Our neighbours have the same tiles, just in different colours which I believe have been painted but possibly they are also available in red, green and yellow.

The same (or very similar) tiles are also used above the top window and also on our porch, which also needs a few replacing.

Comment: Are your siding tiles the same as your roofing tiles?

Comment: @Jeff the tiles differ from the ones on the actual roof, they appear to be smoother and there also corner pieces which I don't believe are available for tiles that would be put on a roof.